# Using jQuery $.each() to iterate through each instance of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object declaration that looks like this:

```
function box(box_Id, box_BackgroundColor, box_Width) {
    this.boxId = box_Id;
    this.boxBackgroundColor = box_BackgroundColor;
    this.boxWidth = box_Width;
}
```

Then, I am creating 3 new instances of that object:

```
var box1 = new box('box1', 'ff0000', 70);
var box2 = new box('box2', '00ff00', 100);
var box3 = new box('box3', '0000ff', 270);
```

Now, I am trying to use the jQuery $.each() function to cycle through each instance of the box() object, and console.log() output one of the variables each time through. I'm using the following code, but nothing shows up in the console:

```
$.each(box, function(){
    console.log("this.boxId = " + this.boxId);
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks a ton!

Comment: [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loops through objects and arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`box` is just a function, you can't iterate on it. There is no way to get all instances of a prototype unless you specifically remember them. For example, this would work:

```
function Box(boxId, boxBackgroundColor, boxWidth) {
    this.boxId = boxId;
    this.boxBackgroundColor = boxBackgroundColor;
    this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
    Box.instances.push(this);
}
Box.instances = [];

var box1 = new Box('box1', 'ff0000', 70);
var box2 = new Box('box2', '00ff00', 100);
var box3 = new Box('box3', '0000ff', 270);

$.each(Box.instances, function(){
    console.log("this.boxId = " + this.boxId);
});
```

A minor note: As a point of JavaScript style, functions that are intended to be used as constructors are commonly written with a title case, to mimic the conventions already present in Java, Ruby, Python etc. Unlike some of those languages, JavaScript does not enforce this convention in any way, so what is written above is in no way a syntax error. But one may think of it as a stylistic error, as it will impede readability of your code to other developers -- both because of their mental model, as well as because of failure of common syntax highlighting tools (as you will note if you compare my code snippet with yours). Similarly, I am not aware of any languages whose style guides use underscore-separated camelcase for identifiers. The standard variable identifier format for JavaScript is plain camelcase. I took the liberty of correcting those, but whether or not you adapt your code to fit the community style guidelines is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

.**[each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**() is used to A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays.

```
function box(box_Id, box_BackgroundColor, box_Width) {
    this.boxId = box_Id;
    this.boxBackgroundColor = box_BackgroundColor;
    this.boxWidth = box_Width;
}
var box1 = new box('box1', 'ff0000', 70);
var box2 = new box('box2', '00ff00', 100);
var box3 = new box('box3', '0000ff', 270);
var boxArr=[box1,box2,box3]
$.each(boxArr, function(){
    console.log("this.boxId = " + this.boxId);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h45A5/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Keep all your boxes `box1`,`box2`,`box3` in an array and iterate over that.

```
function box(box_Id, box_BackgroundColor, box_Width) {
    this.boxId = box_Id;
    this.boxBackgroundColor = box_BackgroundColor;
    this.boxWidth = box_Width;
}
var box1 = new box('box1', 'ff0000', 70);
var box2 = new box('box2', '00ff00', 100);
var box3 = new box('box3', '0000ff', 270);

var boxes = [box1,box2,box3];

$.each(boxes, function(index,b){
    console.log("this.boxId = " + b.boxId);
})
```

you can achieve it by this also

```
$.each(boxes, function(){
    console.log("this.boxId = " + this.boxId); //but $each provides value & index so you can use that as I shown above
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. This way, you won't have to remember the property names:

```
function box(box_Id, box_BackgroundColor, box_Width) {
    this.boxId = box_Id;
    this.boxBackgroundColor = box_BackgroundColor;
    this.boxWidth = box_Width;
}
var box1 = new box('box1', 'ff0000', 70);
var box2 = new box('box2', '00ff00', 100);
var box3 = new box('box3', '0000ff', 270);
var boxArr = [box1, box2, box3];

$.each(boxArr, function (index, box) {
    console.log("--- Considering box" + (index + 1));
    $.each(box, function(prop, value) {
        console.log(prop +" => "+ value);
    });
});
```